# Javafx tableview add boolean value in loop

Tags: java, checkbox, javafx, boolean, tableview

I'm trying to populate a tableview with a boolean value as false in a for loop  for checkbox in the table. My goal is to load a csv file in to tableview with first column as "checkbox", so user can select rows for further task.

When i define the same data inside observableArrayList, it works.

```
public void addPredfined_Data_to_Tableview() {

    studentData_Predefined = FXCollections.observableArrayList(
            new StudentTableModel(false, "James", "Atlanta"),
            new StudentTableModel(false, "Karen", "New York"),
            new StudentTableModel(false, "Robert", "Texas")
            );
    tableView.setItems(studentData_Predefined);
}
```

The problem is when i try to update the tableview inside a for loop, it doesn't  work. The error i get is `IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 0, Size: 0`

```
public void load_CSV_file_to_Tableview() {

    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        studentData_fromCSV = FXCollections.observableArrayList(
                new StudentTableModel(Boolean.FALSE, "James", "Atlanta")
                );
    }
    tableView.setItems(studentData_fromCSV);
}
```

Here is my table model class.

```
package application;

import javafx.beans.property.BooleanProperty;
import javafx.beans.property.SimpleBooleanProperty;
import javafx.beans.property.SimpleStringProperty;

public class StudentTableModel {

    private final BooleanProperty chekboxStudentRow;
    private final SimpleStringProperty studentName;
    private final SimpleStringProperty studentLocation;
    public StudentTableModel(Boolean chekboxStudentRow, String studentName, String studentLocation) {
        super();
        this.chekboxStudentRow = new SimpleBooleanProperty(chekboxStudentRow);
        this.studentName = new SimpleStringProperty(studentName);
        this.studentLocation = new SimpleStringProperty(studentLocation);
    }

    public String getStudentName() {
        return studentName.get();
    }

    public String getStudentLocation() {
        return studentLocation.get();
    }

    public final BooleanProperty chekboxStudentRowProperty() {
        return this.chekboxStudentRow;
    }

    public final boolean isChekboxStudentRow() {
        return this.chekboxStudentRowProperty().get();
    }

    public final void setChekboxStudentRow(final boolean chekboxStudentRow) {
        this.chekboxStudentRowProperty().set(chekboxStudentRow);
    }

}
```

And he is my controller class.

```
package application;

import java.net.URL;
import java.util.ResourceBundle;

import javafx.beans.value.ObservableValue;
import javafx.collections.FXCollections;
import javafx.collections.ObservableList;
import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.fxml.Initializable;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.control.TableColumn;
import javafx.scene.control.TableView;
import javafx.scene.control.cell.CheckBoxTableCell;
import javafx.scene.control.cell.PropertyValueFactory;
import javafx.util.Callback;

public class MainWindowController implements Initializable{

    @FXML public Button btn_addPredefined_data;
    @FXML public Button btn_load_csv_file;

    @FXML public TableView<StudentTableModel> tableView;
    @FXML public TableColumn<StudentTableModel, Boolean> col_CheckBox;
    @FXML public TableColumn<StudentTableModel, String> col_StudentName;
    @FXML public TableColumn<StudentTableModel, String> col_StudentLocation;

    public ObservableList<StudentTableModel> studentData_Predefined = FXCollections.observableArrayList();
    public ObservableList<StudentTableModel> studentData_fromCSV = FXCollections.observableArrayList();

    @Override
    public void initialize(URL location, ResourceBundle resources) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        col_CheckBox.setCellFactory(CheckBoxTableCell.forTableColumn(new Callback<Integer, ObservableValue<Boolean>>() {
            @Override
            public ObservableValue<Boolean> call(Integer param) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                return studentData_Predefined.get(param).chekboxStudentRowProperty();
            }
        }));

        col_StudentName.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<StudentTableModel, String>("studentName"));
        col_StudentLocation.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<StudentTableModel, String>("studentLocation"));

        tableView.setEditable(true);

        btn_addPredefined_data.setOnAction(e -> addPredfined_Data_to_Tableview());
        btn_load_csv_file.setOnAction(e -> load_CSV_file_to_Tableview());

    }

    public void addPredfined_Data_to_Tableview() {

        studentData_Predefined = FXCollections.observableArrayList(
                new StudentTableModel(false, "James", "Atlanta"),
                new StudentTableModel(false, "Karen", "New York"),
                new StudentTableModel(false, "Robert", "Texas")
                );
        tableView.setItems(studentData_Predefined);
    }

    public void load_CSV_file_to_Tableview() {

        for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
            studentData_fromCSV = FXCollections.observableArrayList(
                    new StudentTableModel(Boolean.FALSE, "James", "Atlanta")
                    );
        }
        tableView.setItems(studentData_fromCSV);
    }


}
```

Here is the complete stack trace..

```
Exception in thread "JavaFX Application Thread" java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 0, Size: 0
    at java.util.ArrayList.rangeCheck(ArrayList.java:653)
    at java.util.ArrayList.get(ArrayList.java:429)
    at com.sun.javafx.collections.ObservableListWrapper.get(ObservableListWrapper.java:89)
    at application.MainWindowController$1.call(MainWindowController.java:43)
    at application.MainWindowController$1.call(MainWindowController.java:1)
    at javafx.scene.control.cell.CheckBoxTableCell.getSelectedProperty(CheckBoxTableCell.java:391)
    at javafx.scene.control.cell.CheckBoxTableCell.updateItem(CheckBoxTableCell.java:362)
    at javafx.scene.control.TableCell.updateItem(TableCell.java:663)
    at javafx.scene.control.TableCell.indexChanged(TableCell.java:468)
    at javafx.scene.control.IndexedCell.updateIndex(IndexedCell.java:116)
    at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.skin.TableRowSkinBase.updateCells(TableRowSkinBase.java:533)
    at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.skin.TableRowSkinBase.init(TableRowSkinBase.java:147)
    at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.skin.TableRowSkin.<init>(TableRowSkin.java:64)
    at javafx.scene.control.TableRow.createDefaultSkin(TableRow.java:212)
    at javafx.scene.control.Control.impl_processCSS(Control.java:872)
    at javafx.scene.Node.processCSS(Node.java:9056)
    at javafx.scene.Node.applyCss(Node.java:9153)
    at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.skin.VirtualFlow.setCellIndex(VirtualFlow.java:1964)
    at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.skin.VirtualFlow.getCell(VirtualFlow.java:1797)
    at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.skin.VirtualFlow.getCellLength(VirtualFlow.java:1879)
    at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.skin.VirtualFlow.computeViewportOffset(VirtualFlow.java:2528)
    at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.skin.VirtualFlow.layoutChildren(VirtualFlow.java:1189)
    at javafx.scene.Parent.layout(Parent.java:1087)
    at javafx.scene.Parent.layout(Parent.java:1093)
    at javafx.scene.Parent.layout(Parent.java:1093)
    at javafx.scene.Scene.doLayoutPass(Scene.java:552)
    at javafx.scene.Scene$ScenePulseListener.pulse(Scene.java:2397)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.Toolkit.lambda$runPulse$30(Toolkit.java:355)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.Toolkit.runPulse(Toolkit.java:354)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.Toolkit.firePulse(Toolkit.java:381)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumToolkit.pulse(QuantumToolkit.java:510)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumToolkit.pulse(QuantumToolkit.java:490)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumToolkit.lambda$runToolkit$404(QuantumToolkit.java:319)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.InvokeLaterDispatcher$Future.run(InvokeLaterDispatcher.java:95)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication.lambda$null$148(WinApplication.java:191)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Comment: Which line is throwing the exception? Your `load_CSV_file_to_Tableview` makes no sense, btw, all you do is assign a list of length 1 to `studentData_fromCSV` three times (so at the end, you still have a list of length 1), but I don't think that is where the exception happens.

Comment: @James_D , The exception seems to be happening  at `"tableView.setItems(studentData_fromCSV)"` , because, when i comment out there is no error. And also, tried iterating through the array list to check if the data was loaded. and it did.

Comment: It's impossible for that exception to be thrown by that line. Instead of trial-and-error, why don't you just read the stack trace and see which line it tells you is throwing the exception???

Comment: @James_D , my apologies, I'm new to java and javafx as well. Here are the first few lines from the stack trace ... `Exception in thread "JavaFX Application Thread" java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 0, Size: 0
 at java.util.ArrayList.rangeCheck(ArrayList.java:653)
 at java.util.ArrayList.get(ArrayList.java:429)
 at com.sun.javafx.collections.ObservableListWrapper.get(ObservableListWrapper.java:89)
 at application.MainWindowController$1.call(MainWindowController.java:43)
 at application.MainWindowController$1.call(MainWindowController.java:1)` ,  Looks like it is from ArrayList.

Comment: Post the *complete* stack trace in your question if you don't know [how to read it](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3988788/2775450). Also please remember we can't see the line numbers in your code, so point out which is the relevant line.

Comment: So which line is line 43? (This is like squeezing blood from a stone: do you actually want help here, or not?)

Comment: @James_D , I just posted the complete stack trace, The relevant line here based on the error is from `java.util.ArrayList.rangeCheck(ArrayList.java:653)`

Comment: Sorry, the line 43 is `    return studentData_Predefined.get(param).chekboxStudentRowProperty();
`

Comment: OK, so now the error is pretty obvious, isn't it?

Comment: :-( oops. yes Sir,  my bad.  it should be `return studentData_fromCSV.get(param).chekboxStudentRowProperty();` I learned how to stack trace with this. Thanks a million Sir. I really appreciate your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the `load_CSV_file_to_Tableview()` is invoked, the table's data is set to `studentData_fromCSV` (and presumably `studentData_Predefined` is never populated).

However, your `CheckBoxTableCell` uses `studentData_Predefined` in all cases, so it will try to reference elements in an empty list if `studentData_Predefined` is empty and there is data in the table.

Just reference the table data directly:

```
    col_CheckBox.setCellFactory(CheckBoxTableCell.forTableColumn(new Callback<Integer, ObservableValue<Boolean>>() {
        @Override
        public ObservableValue<Boolean> call(Integer param) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return tableView.getItems().get(param).chekboxStudentRowProperty();
        }
    }));
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your help. You not resolved the issue perfectly but also helped me learn how to read the stack trace. Thanks again !!!

Comment: @Kevin This question: https://stackoverflow.com/q/3988788/2775450 is one of the most useful on SO, imho.

Comment: it sure is, i started reading this. Thank you for your recommendation.